# Set effect on selected cell in uicollectionview(single selection) ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2, ios9

I am using collection view for horizontal scrolling. Its working pretty well. Now I want to set any effect for selecting any cell. So, I wrote this code"

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {   
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell?.layer.borderColor = .None
        cell!.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor


        let dic1 = arr.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        let url = dic1["url"] as! String
        let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

        webviewfortab.loadRequest(request)


    }
```

This sets border for selected cell. But, when I select another cell, both the cell are getting selected but I want only single selection so that when user selects one,old one must be disselected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just have to handle `didDeselect`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

And of course have set single selection on your collection view

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```